# Close toastr.error after a few seconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using `toastr.error('Testing pop-up')` in **Javascript** to show me a pop-up when there is an error in the application, but I can't see in the official documentation how to close this pop-up after X seconds automatically without pressing any button. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Have you try `toastr.error('Testing pop-up',{timeOut: 5000})` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for the `error` function is:

```js
            function error(message, title, optionsOverride) {
```

https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/50092cc604850a16c985520b63df184d3e0b4086/toastr.js#L46

You can pass options to hide it as needed.

You can play with the options to see the best fit in the demo page:

https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set timeout like:

**Timeouts**
Control how toastr interacts with users by setting timeouts appropriately.

```
toastr.options.timeOut = 30; // How long the toast will display without user interaction
toastr.options.extendedTimeOut = 60; // How long the toast will display after a user hovers over it
```

Reference:

- [Official DOC](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)
- [Playable example](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)